# Python bottle requests and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, bottle

I'm building a small RESTful API with bottle in python and am currently experiencing an issue with character encodings when working with the request object.

Hitting up `http://server.com/api?q=äöü` and looking at `request.query['q']` on the server gets me "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼", which is obviously not what I'm looking for.

Same goes for a POST request containing the form-urlencoded key `q` with the value `äöü`. `request.forms.get('q')` contains "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼".

What's going on here? I don't really have the option of decoding these elements with a different encoding or do I? Is there a general option for bottle to store these in unicode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`request.query['q']` and `forms.get('q')` return the raw byte value submitted by the web browser. The value `äöü`, submitted by a browser as UTF-8 encoded bytes, is `'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'`.

If you print that byte string, and the place you're printing it to interprets it as ISO-8859-1, or the similar Windows code page 1252, you will get `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼`. If you are debugging by printing to a Windows command prompt, or a file displayed by Notepad, that's why.

If you use the [alternative direct property access](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#introducing-forms) `request.query.q` or `forms.q` Bottle will give you Unicode strings instead, decoded from the byte version using UTF-8. It's usually best to work with these Unicode strings wherever you can. (Though still you may have trouble printing them to console. The Windows command prompt is notoriously terrible at coping with non-ASCII characters, and as such is a bad place to be debugging Unicode issues.)

Comment: I had no idea direct property access like this was possible. Thank you!

Comment: Must use in the form of dictionary to search the properties for non-standard be sending the POST. There is another alternative Different this `request.POST.question_10` as such `request.POST ["question_10"]`?

Comment: If you need to read a property with a non-identifier or dynamic name, you can always use `getattr` as with any other object. eg `getattr(forms, 'q')`

Answer (score 1):

There's also the alternative of using `def getunicode(self, name, default=None, encoding=None)`

Instead of using

```
request.forms.get('some_form_field_name')
```

try

```
request.forms.getunicode('some_form_field_name')
```

That'll handle non-latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, to convert it ,I did like this search_field.encode("ISO-8859-1").decode("utf-8")