# How to get utf-8 from forms in Bottle?

Tags: python, forms, encoding, utf-8, bottle

I am trying to use Bottle.py to get input information from users in a web page.

Everything works fine except when I have latin characters (accents mostly). I have try using utf-8 and latin-1 coding on the first two lines of the code, but it won't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import bottle

@bottle.post('/newpost')
def post_newpost():
    subject = bottle.request.forms.get("subject")
    body = bottle.request.forms.get("body")
    tags = bottle.request.forms.get("tags")
```

and the html code from the page is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>New Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/newpost" method="POST">

<h2>Post title</h2>
<input type="text" name="subject" size="120" value="{{subject}}" ><br>
<h2>Post<h2>
<textarea name="body" cols="120" rows="20">{{body}}</textarea><br>
<h2>Tags</h2>
<input type="text" name="tags" size="120" value="{{tags}}"><br>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

I read in Bottle page that:

- In Python 3 all strings are unicode, but HTTP is a byte-based wire
  protocol. The server has to decode the byte strings somehow before
  they are passed to the application. To be on the safe side, WSGI
  suggests ISO-8859-1 (aka latin1), a reversible single-byte codec that
  can be re-encoded with a different encoding later. Bottle does that
  for FormsDict.getunicode() and attribute access, but not for the
  dict-access methods. These return the unchanged values as provided by
  the server implementation, which is probably not what you want.

  > > > request.query['city']

  'GÃ¶ttingen' # An utf8 string provisionally decoded as ISO-8859-1 by the server

  > > > request.query.city

  'Göttingen'  # The same string correctly re-encoded as utf8 by bottle

If you need the whole dictionary with correctly decoded values (e.g. for WTForms), you can call FormsDict.decode() to get a re-encoded copy.

After reading that I tried using that function but don't know how. 
Right now Bottle form returns strings, so I can not use encode('utf-8') or decode('utf-8').

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432211/python-bottle-requests-and-unicode

Comment: I saw that question, but fail to implement it too. Tried to write subject = bottle.request.forms.get.subject and got error.

Comment: I found out my mistake, I had to write subject=bottle.request.forms.subject... without the get..  Thanks!

Comment: I had this same problem. Your answer below works great.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import bottle

@bottle.post('/newpost')
def post_newpost():
    subject = bottle.request.forms.subject
    body = bottle.request.forms.body
    tags = bottle.request.forms.tags
```

That will do it.... Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is not doing anything here.